# Sender/receiver behavior when receiver responds in network programming with broadcast

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I am learning about broadcasting in network programming (using C). From what I understand, a sender sends a message to all the receivers (who are listening) in the local area network. Using my local machine with a virtual machine I wrote a small program to see how things work.

Code for `receiver.c` (I put this code on my local machine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>

#define PORT 4242

int main() {
    int socket_fd, sender_size;
    struct sockaddr_in receiver, sender;
    char receive_buff[256], send_buff[256];

    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd < 0) {
        perror("failed to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    int broadcast_yes = 1, reuse_yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void*) &broadcast_yes, sizeof(broadcast_yes)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to set broadcast socket option");
        return -2;
    }

    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*) &reuse_yes, sizeof(reuse_yes)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to set reuse socket option");
        return -3;
    }

    memset(&receiver, 0, sizeof(receiver));
    receiver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    receiver.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    receiver.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &receiver, sizeof(receiver)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to bind");
        return -4;
    }

    printf("Listening...\n");
    memset(receive_buff, 0, sizeof(receive_buff));
    sender_size = sizeof(sender);
    if (recvfrom(socket_fd, (void*)receive_buff, sizeof(receive_buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &sender, &sender_size) < 0) {
        perror("failed to receive broadcast message");
        return -5;
    }

    printf("%s\n", receive_buff);

    strcpy(send_buff, "got your message");
    if (sendto(socket_fd, (void*)send_buff, sizeof(send_buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &sender, sizeof(sender)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to send confirmation message");
        return -6;
    }

    close(socket_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Code for `sender.c` (I put this code on my virtual machine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 4242

int main() {
    int socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in receiver;
    char send_buff[256], receive_buff[256];
    socklen_t receiver_size;

    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd < 0) {
        perror("failed to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    int broadcast_yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void*) &broadcast_yes, sizeof(broadcast_yes)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to set broadcast socket option");
        return -2;
    }

    memset(&receiver, 0, sizeof(receiver));
    receiver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    receiver.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    receiver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.255");

    strcpy(send_buff, "i'm sending a broadcast message");
    if (sendto(socket_fd, (void*)send_buff, strlen(send_buff) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &receiver, sizeof(receiver)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to send broadcast message");
        return -3;
    }

    memset(receive_buff, 0, sizeof(receive_buff));
    receiver_size = sizeof(receiver);
    if (recvfrom(socket_fd, (void*)receive_buff, sizeof(receive_buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &receiver, &receiver_size) < 0) {
        perror("failed to receive confirmation message");
        return -4;
    }

    printf("%s\n", receive_buff);

    close(socket_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing fancy. The `sender` sends the message `i'm sending a broadcast message` as a broadcast message (since I put `255` at the end of the IPv4 address and I also set the `SO_BROADCAST` option in the socket). In turn, the `receiver` waits and receives this message. It also has that `SO_BROADCAST` option enabled in the socket. What happens afterwards is what is confusing to me. As you can see above after the `receiver` receives the message, it sends a confirmation message `got your message` back to the sender.

But what if a sender sends the message to all receivers (listeners) in the LAN and there are MULTIPLE receivers in the LAN, how would this work? Wouldn't EACH of the multiple receivers send that `got your message` confirmation message to the sender? So it would be like multiple machines have that code in `receiver.c` and each of these machine would get the `sender`'s address information in the variable `struct sockaddr_in sender` when the code calls the function `recvfrom()`. Then, ALL of these machines will send that message `got your message` to the `sender`. But the sender has only one `recvfrom()` function call so it will receive only the first message which arrives to it. The confirmation messages of the other receivers will be lost. Or at least that's what I think is going to happen. How can I solve this and get all the confirmation messages? Again, this question only applies if my understanding of what happens that I stated above is true, which I don't know if it is so I would also ask you if I am correct in thinking that the sender will only receive one confirmation message.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

If you broadcast a message and multiple instances of the receiver get it, *each* of the will send a response back to the sender.

This means that the sender needs to call `recvfrom` in a loop to receive multiple messages.  But at the same time you don't want the sender to wait forever since you don't know how many responses you'll get.

The simplest way to handle this is to use the `select` function to check if there's data to read.  You can give this function a timeout so you can control how long it waits.  If it returns a positive value, there's data to read and you can call `recvfrom` to read a response, then call `select` again to wait for more.  If it returns 0, then it timed out waiting for a response.